# Is there a way to hide a project in Solution Explorer programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

I am working on an extension for Visual Studio 2010, and I am attempting to figure out how to hide a project in Solution Explorer (the `UIHierarchy`), without removing it from the underlying solution.  I have been searching, and have found some clues, but I just don't know enough to put it all together.

From what I've been able to gather, Visual Studio does not even create a `UIHierarchy` instance unless the item is visible (ie, the tree has been expanded to it), so I figured that if I wanted an item to go away, I should be able to simply remove the instance from the tree.

**My first question is, is my assumption correct?**

Assuming the answer is yes, then I have the following code (simplified for this post):

```
private void HideProject(IVsHierarchy project)
{
    ((IVsUIHierarchyWindow2)_uiHierarchyWindow).RemoveUIHierarchy(GetUIHierarchyFromHierarchy(project));
}

private IVsUIHierarchy GetUIHierarchyFromHierarchy(IVsHierarchy project)
{
    UIHierarchy solutionExplorer = ((DTE2)_dte).ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
    foreach (UIHierarchyItem hierarchy in solutionExplorer.UIHierarchyItems.Item(1).UIHierarchyItems)
    {
        // What do I do here?
    }
    return null;
}
```

Obviously, this does not do anything yet, because I am completely stuck.  I suspect that the code will have to become recursive (to handle projects contained in folders, etc.), but for now, I am only concerned about the simple case where all the projects are contained directly below the solution.

Does anybody know of any better reference material than Microsoft's (IMHO deficient) documentation?  Has anybody tried to do this before?  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: as for better documentation - I guess you'll find some helpfull info in MSDN VSX forum. Also you could look for open source MPF based packages (there are some product available) and learn how they did the tricks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am not sure it is possible for project nodes.** As for file nodes there is a VSHPROPID_IsNonMemberItem hierarchy property. Look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/1db1ca96-0c1a-4e32-a790-f8332c7b909e), and [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vsx/thread/C635535C-F794-432B-901A-00129942C1FA) also.

Comment: Dang, it's beginning to look that I can't do what I'm trying to do.  Setting the flags for file nodes on a project throws all kinds of errors.  Thanks for the help, anyway, though!